# Lost my way in Minecraft - How do I teleport to a certain un-named entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am wondering how to teleport back to a pack of wolves I left sitting near my house that I now cannot locate. I want to get back to my house and keep building it.

Is there any way to teleport to the wolves, even if I didn't name them? I also left a horse outside that is tamed.. how do I teleport to that horse?

Is it possible to teleport to a certain object, such as a gate, or a block?

I'm stumped and I've searched the entire internet...

I have a command block if that helps. I don't know the coords for my old place though.

Comment: Try using the @e for entity and then specifying it to your certain creature or mob. This is the [Site](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands) for you

Answer (score 1):

*If one of your pets is loaded*, you should be able to teleport to it, although it's going to take some setup first.  You'll also need access to commands (obviously) beyond `/tp`.

First thing to do is give all your tamed animals a score on the scoreboard.  Set up the scoreboard with `/scoreboard objectives add tamed dummy`.

Next, you need to set the score for each of your tamed animals.  In order to do this in 1.8, you're going to need to know your personal UUID.  You can find out what that is [here](http://mcuuid.net).  In 1.8 and later use `/scoreboard players set @e tamed 1 {OwnerUUID:"<your UUID>"}` (omit `<` and `>`).  Prior to 1.8, you would use the datatag `{Owner:"<your username>"}`.

Then it's a simple matter of teleporting yourself to one of your animals: `/tp @p @e[score_tamed_min=1,c=1]` (the `c=1` is there to select only one tamed animal, otherwise the command will fail).

---

As I said in the beginning, your animals need to be loaded for this to work.  If they are present in one of your spawn chunks, my belief is that they should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods of getting home, considering you have cheats on (which you obviously do: you have a command block)

**METHOD 1**

Type the command `/tp YOURNAME @r[type=Wolf]` The selector used here, `@r`, usually defaults to players, but with the `[type=Wolf]` selector, it now applies to wolves. This could also be applied to horses, if you think you have less of those. To find out, type `/testfor @e[type=EntityHorse]` and then `/testfor @e[type=Wolf]`.

**METHOD 2**

This method, unfortunately, involves dying. If you have a valid (adequate space around it, last one you slept in) bed, it resets your spawn. If you have valuable or symbolic or useful items in your inventory that you want to keep, type `/gamerule keepInventory true` , then type `/kill` . This will kill you and you respawn with all yours items. Alternitavely, craft a compass, which will lead you back to your spawn.

---

Next time you're thinking "Houston, we have a problem!" just refer to the above methods.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot teleport to an unnamed entity or a block without knowing its location.

Comment: Pretty sure you're wrong, at least in this instance.

Comment: In 1.8 you can target entities with @e so yes you can.